# create HWND in c#

Tags: c#

am import some dll for create the live video. here myprob is i have c++ code like

int PLAYER_SDK_SPEC CreatePlayer( HWND hWndParent, RECT& rectPlayer, const char* szWndTitle );

in c# i have import dll like

[DllImport("PlayerLib")]
    public static extern int CreatePlayer(IntPtr Handle, Rectangle RECT, StringBuilder szWndTitle);

am call that funcation like 
CreatePlayer( this.Handle, rect, str6);

but it's generate  some unhandled exception... please help me to solve this prob
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the P/Invoke declaration is correct. From what I know it should be:

```
[DllImport("PlayerLib")] 
public static extern int CreatePlayer(IntPtr Handle, ref Rectangle RECT, String szWndTitle);
```

The original version takes a reference to a rectangle, so you should do the same. Also I'm not sure if the `Rectangle` type and the `RECT` type of C++ are equal. Maybe you have to declare a  `struct RECT` in C# too.

Take a look at [pinvoke.net](http://pinvoke.net). There you'll find functions that take `RECT` parameters too, you'll find hints there on how to pass a rectangle to a C++ function.